# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: - pil -> python 2.6* - python 3.6*

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import

I'm trying to install `PIL` using anaconda, while I'm inside my conda environment.

Inside the conda environment:

```
conda install pil
```

but I get the following error

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
 - pil -> python 2.6*
 - python 3.6*
```

I have python 2.7 and 3.6 both installed inside my conda environment. `PIL` is not currently installed as I get an `importError` when I try to import it in python.

I have tried the following:

```
conda uninstall pil
```

and

```
conda remove pil
```

For both I get

```
PackageNotFoundError: Package(s) is missing from the environment:
        pil
```

What do I do?

Comment: `pip install pillow`

Comment: Do not install `pil` but `pillow`.

Comment: @SmartManoj If I do that it says `Requirement already satisfied`

Comment: @Sraw Okay i did `conda install pillow` and it installed. But when I try to import it in python it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'`

Comment: It is installed by `pillow` but imported by `PIL`.

Comment: Full steps: 1. Make sure `PIL` is removed(`conda remove pil`, `pip uninstall pil`) 2. Install `Pillow` 3. Use it just like `PIL`(`from PIL import ...`)

Answer (score 3):

You can install `pillow` instead, which supports both Python 2 and 3 (check out the [supported versions here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/installation.html#notes)

`conda install pillow`

`pil` is deprecated since 2009 and `pillow` is an actively developed fork of `pil`.

So I'd suggest creating a new environment with `pillow` installed instead of `pil` to test.